# Cart66 localization hardcode strings

Tags: plugins, localization

I've read the documentation http://cart66.com/cart66lite-documentation.pdf and searched on google but i can't seem to find a location(s) to localize strings (hardcode) for Cart66.

If someone can point me to the right direction.

EDIT1:

I've changed CART66_CURRENCY_SYMBOL field in the wp_cart66_cart_settings table to have my own currency.

But i still need to localize the string. I changed the cart66.po and it's not working.
Please help.

EDIT2:

Modified php scripts in views folder to localize strings and format the currency with price accordingly. SOLVED.

Comment: Please move your EDIT to a separate answer if this solved the problem.

Comment: i just solved a tiny bit of my problem

Comment: Ah, ok. Seemed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the localisation of your WP install, which I dont know how to do - and whatever local you choose, cart will automatically choose that language file.  I havent done it yet but that seems the way:  http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cart66-running-on-another-language

You can hard change the cart.php file, but like changing views folder any plugin updates will wipe it.  take out the php stuff and hard code your new words instead

Answer (score 0):

To change the currency symbol, do so in the settings for the plugin.

[image: See here]